# Extract the JSON data inside the array column in Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, java, json, pandas, dataframe

I am working on extracting JSON array column in dataframe in Python using Pandas Library, where I have a data like this

```
>df

id      partnerid   payments

5263    org1244     [{"sNo": 1, "amount":"1000"}, {"sNo": 2, "amount":"500"}]
5264    org1245     [{"sNo": 1, "amount":"2000"}, {"sNo": 2, "amount":"600"}]
5265    org1246     [{"sNo": 1, "amount":"3000"}, {"sNo": 2, "amount":"700"}]
```

I want to extract the JSON data inside the list and add it as a column in same dataframe
like this

```
>mod_df

id      partnerid   sNo amount

5263    org1244     1   1000
5263    org1244     2   500
5264    org1245     1   2000
5264    org1245     2   600
5265    org1246     1   3000
5265    org1246     2   700
```

I have tried with this approach

```
import pandas as pd
import json as j

df = pd.read_parquet('sample.parquet')

js_loads = df['payments'].apply(j.loads)
js_list = list(js_loads)
j_data = j.dumps(js_list)
df = df.join(pd.read_json(j_data))
df = df.drop(columns=['payments'] , axis=1)
```

But this works, only if we have JSON data in column not list of JSON.
Can someone explain, how can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to `list` by `ast.literal_eval` and use `explode()`to  transform each element to a row and also replicate the other columns.

Then, use `.apply(pd.Series)` to convert dict-like to `series`.

Finally, concatenate to original dataframe using `pd.concat()`.

---

Example:

```
import ast

# sample data
d = {'col1': [0, 1, 2], 'payments': ['[{"sNo": 1, "amount":"1000"}, {"sNo": 2, "amount":"500"}]', '[{"sNo": 1, "amount":"2000"}, {"sNo": 2, "amount":"600"}]', '[{"sNo": 1, "amount":"3000"}, {"sNo": 2, "amount":"700"}]']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2])

df['payments'] = df['payments'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = df.explode('payments') 
out = pd.concat([df.drop(['payments'], axis=1), df['payments'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

> ```
>   col1 sNo amount
> 0 0   1   1000
> 1 0   2   500
> 2 1   1   2000
> 3 1   2   600
> 4 2   1   3000
> 5 2   2   700
> ```

Comment: ast.literal_eval is telling me malformed node or string: [{'val1': 2.5, 'val2': 0.0}]

Comment: if `[{'val1': 2.5, 'val2': 0.0}]` is the string representation of list, it should work.